# How can I take data from elasticsearch to relational database such as Oracle?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, logstash, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-transfer

This situation confused me. We use elasticsearch and Logstash in our company. I need open source PaaS or SaaS tools to import data from Elasticsearch to Oracle / SQL server database. I would be pleased if you have any known and available advice.
(Also, I tried to optimize Apache Nifi and it is not usefull.)

Comment: what if you used Elasticsearch rest api to pull the data into the oracle db using pl/sql packages?

Comment: This process needs to be done simultaneously from about 3600 servers. Unfortunately pl/sql packages are not very successfull in this regard.

Comment: there's a hive solution for els...and we have hive integration...might be something to look into

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably thought of this. but, maybe making a quick script that grabs your ES data and stores it in your SQL server could be the straight forward solution.

That in mind! how much data do you have? and why was the manual script solution evaded?

Comment: We tried to do this, but we cannot get a successful result because the amount of data is too large. I want to use an open source product serving this area. The amount of data continues to increase too much simultaneously and it is not possible to do it manually with a script.